# SQLite Foreign Key constraint 'Ignore extra data'

Tags: database, sqlite, foreign-keys, constraints

I need to create 2 tables that has following data. Parent table `A` has column `id` which is a `Primary Key`.

Table `A`:

```
+----+--------+
| id | Animal |
+----+--------+
| 1  | Dog    |
| 2  | Monkey |
| 3  | Bear   |
| 4  | Tiger  |
+----+--------+
```

Another table `B` has a foreign key `id1` that refers to the Key `id` of the table `A`.

Table `B`:

```
+-----+---------+
| id1 | Desc    |
+-----+---------+
| 1   | barks   |
| 2   | jumps   |
| 3   | attacks |
| 4   | roars   |
| 5   | eats    |
+-----+---------+
```

I am able to make Table `A` and insert data. I am able to make Table `B`, but when I am trying to insert data (with extra value `5`) in Table `B` it is giving error `SQLITE_CONSTRAINT(787): FOREIGN KEY constraint failed` which is obvious. My question is how do I make SQLite to insert only data that complies with Primary Key and ignore the extra data resulting in the output seen in Table `C`

Table `C`:

```
+-----+---------+
| id1 | Desc    |
+-----+---------+
| 1   | barks   |
| 2   | jumps   |
| 3   | attacks |
| 4   | roars   |
+-----+---------+
```

The SQLite query I am trying to run looks like this:

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF;
CREATE TABLE temp_tbl AS SELECT * FROM TableB;
DROP TABLE TableB;
CREATE TABLE TableB (id1 INTEGER REFERENCES TableA(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,Desc VARCHAR); 
INSERT INTO TableB(id1,Desc) SELECT id1,Desc FROM temp_tbl;
DROP TABLE temp_tbl;
PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert only the rows that have a match:

```
INSERT INTO TableB(id1, Desc)
SELECT id1, Desc FROM temp_tbl
WHERE id1 IN (SELECT id FROM TableA);
```